# When I enable the HTTP port 80 in AWS Beanstalk Load Balancer settings it rollback to previous configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-redirect, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm using the PHP8 application using NGINX server.

This is current load balancer setting see the below picture:

[image]

When I'm trying to enable port 80 in configurations I getting the following error message:

[image]

Due to this http to https redirection is not working.

This is working fine on test servers but not working on Dev server.

Comment: Go to EC2 console, and check on the actually load balancer what's happening. What options it has.

Comment: Actually it issue due to CloudFormation stack yaml file configuration. I have no idea How to add the Updating Auto Scaling group named: Provided Target Groups may not be valid. Please ensure they exist and try again